# Objective C dot operator nowadays

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm learning this from a 'newish' book, but I'm wondering what the current standard is as to the use of the dot operator for things outside of setting property values.

As in method calls and whatnot.  Obviously `myClass.myMethod:value` is syntactically correct, but is it an accepted norm nowadays?

The dot operator is much more 'human' feeling than `[myClass myMethod:myValue]` in my opinion.

Comment: I like bracket syntax! Must not be a human :[

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried compiling this? Your example of myClass.myMethod:value is not valid as far as I understand it.

The dot operator is translated by the compiler to either `-(void)setMyValue:(ValueType*)` or  `-(ValueType*)myValue` depending on if you are getting or setting it.

Read the apple documentation for more info:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW17

Comment: Even in the case where its syntactically allowed to have a method with no params and only a return value, people will abuse this as syntax sugar (avoid braces), and Clang *will warn you* - using an accessor method to mutate values is not OK.  dot syntax is meant for property access ONLY.